# QML state: not taken into account if it's not a child of its target

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Assuming I have a rectangle and a state block:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4



Window{
    id: main
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true
    Item{

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"
        state: "ready"
    }

    states: [
            State {
                name: "ready"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    color: "lightblue"
                    opacity: 0.2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Why is it that when I specify an initial `State` for my `Rectangle`, it is not affected by the above `states`. Please note that the `states` block is outside of the `Rectangle`, I assumed since there's a target, there's no need to put it inside the `Rectangle` block.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: It only works if `states` is inside the `Rectangle`. Is there a way to define the `states` separately and still get the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The states belong to an item so when you point state: "ready" in the Rectangle is looking in the states of the rectangle, not on the states of the other items. So you have 2 solutions:

**1.** Set the initial state within Window:

```
Window{
    id: main
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true
    Item{

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
        }

        state: "ready"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "ready"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    color: "lightblue"
                    opacity: 0.2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**2.** Move the states to Rectangle to be their states.

```
Window{
    id: main
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true
    Item{

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            state: "ready"

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "ready"
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: rect
                        color: "lightblue"
                        opacity: 0.2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }  
}
```

If you want from another Item to assign the initial state you must use the reference to the item, in the following example the states belong to Item with `id: it` and then we establish it when the Rectangle completes its construction:

```
Window{
    id: main
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true
    Item{
        id: it
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "red"
            Component.onCompleted: it.state = "ready"
        }
        states: [
            State {
                name: "ready"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: rect
                    color: "lightblue"
                    opacity: 0.2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: option 1 is what I was looking for, thanks. Is there a way to share `states` with other rectangles or is it only 1 target assignment?

Comment: @bardao It is by element, but in the same properties you can modify other rectangles: `State {
                name: "ready" PropertyChanges { target: rect1; color: "lightblue"; opacity: 0.2}
            PropertyChanges { target: rect2; olor: "lightblue"; opacity: 0.2"} ...`